# When IP header of length 22bytes is there then how padding will work?

Tags: ip, ipv4, protocol-theory

My base IPv4 header of 20bytes + 2bytes i used for Options making it 22bytes means 176bits so padding will add 16 Zeroes to make it multiple of 32? is this correct way to understand?

Boundary of 32bits means counting all fields top to bottom or left to right?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your IPv4 header is 22 octets, you must add two octets (16 bits) of zero padding to make it 24 octets. The number of octets in the IPv4 header must be a multiple of four octets (32 bits), up to the limit of 60 octets.

You must also adjust the IHL field to reflect the number of 32-bit words. For a normal 20-octet header, the IHL will be five, but you are adding one 32-bit word, so your IHL must be six.

> Boundary of 32bits means counting all fields top to bottom or left to
> right?

That question doesn't actually make sense. The IPv4 header is a stream of bits sent serially, and the padding is added to the end of the header.

---

Also, understand that there are other rules around IPv4 header options (you cannot simply make up your own), and all hosts in the packet path, including intermediate routers, must understand the options, most of which are deprecated or unsupported. Most routers today are configured to drop IPv4 packets with options.

*[RFC 791, Internet Protocol, Section 3.1 Internet Header Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1)* has an explanation about IPv4 header options:

> Options: variable
>
> The options may appear or not in datagrams. They must be implemented
> by all IP modules (host and gateways).  What is optional is their
> transmission in any particular datagram, not their implementation.
>
> In some environments the security option may be required in all
> datagrams.
>
> The option field is variable in length.  There may be zero or more
> options. There are two cases for the format of an option:
>
> ```
> Case 1: A single octet of option-type.
>
> Case 2: An option-type octet, an option-length octet, and the actual option-data octets.
> ```
>
> The option-length octet counts the option-type octet and the
> option-length octet as well as the option-data octets.
>
> The option-type octet is viewed as having 3 fields:
>
> ```
> 1 bit   copied flag,
> 2 bits  option class,
> 5 bits  option number.
> ```
>
> The copied flag indicates that this option is copied into all
> fragments on fragmentation.
>
> ```
> 0 = not copied
> 1 = copied
> ```
>
> The option classes are:
>
> ```
> 0 = control
> 1 = reserved for future use
> 2 = debugging and measurement
> 3 = reserved for future use
> ```
>
> The following internet options are defined:
>
> ```
> CLASS NUMBER LENGTH DESCRIPTION
> ----- ------ ------ -----------
>   0     0      -    End of Option list.  This option occupies only
>                     1 octet; it has no length octet.
>   0     1      -    No Operation. This option occupies only 1
>                     octet; it has no length octet.
>   0     2     11    Security. Used to carry Security,
>                     Compartmentation, User Group (TCC), and
>                     Handling Restriction Codes compatible with DOD
>                     requirements.
>   0     3     var.  Loose Source Routing. Used to route the
>                     internet datagram based on information
>                     supplied by the source.
>   0     9     var.  Strict Source Routing. Used to route the
>                     internet datagram based on information
>                     supplied by the source.
>   0     7     var.  Record Route. Used to trace the route an
>                     internet datagram takes.
>   0     8      4    Stream ID. Used to carry the stream
>                     identifier.
>   2     4     var.  Internet Timestamp.
> ```
>
> Specific Option Definitions
>
> End of Option List
>
> ```
>   +--------+
>   |00000000|
>   +--------+
>     Type=0
> ```
>
> This option indicates the end of the option list.  This might not
> coincide with the end of the internet header according to the internet
> header length. This is used at the end of all options, not the end of
> each option, and need only be used if the end of the options would not
> otherwise coincide with the end of the internet header.
>
> May be copied, introduced, or deleted on fragmentation, or for any
> other reason.
>
> No Operation
>
> ```
>   +--------+
>   |00000001|
>   +--------+
>     Type=1
> ```
>
> This option may be used between options, for example, to align the
> beginning of a subsequent option on a 32 bit boundary.
>
> May be copied, introduced, or deleted on fragmentation, or for any
> other reason.
>
> Security
>
> This option provides a way for hosts to send security,
> compartmentation, handling restrictions, and TCC (closed user group)
> parameters. The format for this option is as follows:
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+---//---+---//---+---//---+---//---+
> |10000010|00001011|SSS  SSS|CCC  CCC|HHH  HHH|  TCC   |
> +--------+--------+---//---+---//---+---//---+---//---+
>  Type=130 Length=11
> ```
>
> Security (S field):  16 bits
>
> Specifies one of 16 levels of security (eight of which are reserved
> for future use).
>
> ```
> 00000000 00000000 - Unclassified
> 11110001 00110101 - Confidential
> 01111000 10011010 - EFTO
> 10111100 01001101 - MMMM
> 01011110 00100110 - PROG
> 10101111 00010011 - Restricted
> 11010111 10001000 - Secret
> 01101011 11000101 - Top Secret
> 00110101 11100010 - (Reserved for future use)
> 10011010 11110001 - (Reserved for future use)
> 01001101 01111000 - (Reserved for future use)
> 00100100 10111101 - (Reserved for future use)
> 00010011 01011110 - (Reserved for future use)
> 10001001 10101111 - (Reserved for future use)
> 11000100 11010110 - (Reserved for future use)
> 11100010 01101011 - (Reserved for future use)
> ```
>
> Compartments (C field):  16 bits
>
> An all zero value is used when the information transmitted is not
> compartmented. Other values for the compartments field may be obtained
> from the Defense Intelligence Agency.
>
> Handling Restrictions (H field):  16 bits
>
> The values for the control and release markings are alphanumeric
> digraphs and are defined in the Defense Intelligence Agency Manual
> DIAM 65-19, "Standard Security Markings".
>
> Transmission Control Code (TCC field):  24 bits
>
> Provides a means to segregate traffic and define controlled
> communities of interest among subscribers. The TCC values are
> trigraphs, and are available from HQ DCA Code 530.
>
> Must be copied on fragmentation. This option appears at most once in a
> datagram.
>
> Loose Source and Record Route
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
> |10000011| length | pointer|     route data    |
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
>  Type=131
> ```
>
> The loose source and record route (LSRR) option provides a means for
> the source of an internet datagram to supply routing information to be
> used by the gateways in forwarding the datagram to the destination,
> and to record the route information.
>
> The option begins with the option type code.  The second octet is the
> option length which includes the option type code and the length
> octet, the pointer octet, and length-3 octets of route data. The third
> octet is the pointer into the route data indicating the octet which
> begins the next source address to be processed. The pointer is
> relative to this option, and the smallest legal value for the pointer
> is 4.
>
> A route data is composed of a series of internet addresses. Each
> internet address is 32 bits or 4 octets. If the pointer is greater
> than the length, the source route is empty (and the recorded route
> full) and the routing is to be based on the destination address field.
>
> If the address in destination address field has been reached and the
> pointer is not greater than the length, the next address in the source
> route replaces the address in the destination address field, and the
> recorded route address replaces the source address just used, and
> pointer is increased by four.
>
> The recorded route address is the internet module's own internet
> address as known in the environment into which this datagram is being
> forwarded.
>
> This procedure of replacing the source route with the recorded route
> (though it is in the reverse of the order it must be in to be used as
> a source route) means the option (and the IP header as a whole)
> remains a constant length as the datagram progresses through the
> internet.
>
> This option is a loose source route because the gateway or host IP is
> allowed to use any route of any number of other intermediate gateways
> to reach the next address in the route.
>
> Must be copied on fragmentation. Appears at most once in a datagram.
>
> Strict Source and Record Route
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
> |10001001| length | pointer|     route data    |
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
>  Type=137
> ```
>
> The strict source and record route (SSRR) option provides a means for
> the source of an internet datagram to supply routing information to be
> used by the gateways in forwarding the datagram to the destination,
> and to record the route information.
>
> The option begins with the option type code. The second octet is the
> option length which includes the option type code and the length
> octet, the pointer octet, and length-3 octets of route data. The third
> octet is the pointer into the route data indicating the octet which
> begins the next source address to be processed. The pointer is
> relative to this option, and the smallest legal value for the pointer
> is 4.
>
> A route data is composed of a series of internet addresses. Each
> internet address is 32 bits or 4 octets.  If the pointer is greater
> than the length, the source route is empty (and the recorded route
> full) and the routing is to be based on the destination address field.
>
> If the address in destination address field has been reached and the
> pointer is not greater than the length, the next address in the source
> route replaces the address in the destination address field, and the
> recorded route address replaces the source address just used, and
> pointer is increased by four.
>
> The recorded route address is the internet module's own internet
> address as known in the environment into which this datagram is being
> forwarded.
>
> This procedure of replacing the source route with the recorded route
> (though it is in the reverse of the order it must be in to be used as
> a source route) means the option (and the IP header as a whole)
> remains a constant length as the datagram progresses through the
> internet.
>
> This option is a strict source route because the gateway or host IP
> must send the datagram directly to the next address in the source
> route through only the directly connected network indicated in the
> next address to reach the next gateway or host specified in the route.
>
> Must be copied on fragmentation. Appears at most once in a datagram.
>
> Record Route
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
> |00000111| length | pointer|     route data    |
> +--------+--------+--------+---------//--------+
>   Type=7
> ```
>
> The record route option provides a means to record the route of an
> internet datagram.
>
> The option begins with the option type code.  The second octet is the
> option length which includes the option type code and the length
> octet, the pointer octet, and length-3 octets of route data. The third
> octet is the pointer into the route data indicating the octet which
> begins the next area to store a route address. The pointer is relative
> to this option, and the smallest legal value for the pointer is 4.
>
> A recorded route is composed of a series of internet addresses. Each
> internet address is 32 bits or 4 octets.  If the pointer is greater
> than the length, the recorded route data area is full. The originating
> host must compose this option with a large enough route data area to
> hold all the address expected. The size of the option does not change
> due to adding addresses. The intitial contents of the route data area
> must be zero.
>
> When an internet module routes a datagram it checks to see if the
> record route option is present. If it is, it inserts its own internet
> address as known in the environment into which this datagram is being
> forwarded into the recorded route begining at the octet indicated by
> the pointer, and increments the pointer by four.
>
> If the route data area is already full (the pointer exceeds the
> length) the datagram is forwarded without inserting the address into
> the recorded route. If there is some room but not enough room for a
> full address to be inserted, the original datagram is considered to be
> in error and is discarded.  In either case an ICMP parameter problem
> message may be sent to the source host [3].
>
> Not copied on fragmentation, goes in first fragment only. Appears at
> most once in a datagram.
>
> Stream Identifier
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> |10001000|00000010|    Stream ID    |
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>  Type=136 Length=4
> ```
>
> This option provides a way for the 16-bit SATNET stream identifier to
> be carried through networks that do not support the stream concept.
>
> Must be copied on fragmentation. Appears at most once in a datagram.
>
> Internet Timestamp
>
> ```
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> |01000100| length | pointer|oflw|flg|
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> |         internet address          |
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> |             timestamp             |
> +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> |                 .                 |
>                   .
>                   .
> Type = 68
> ```
>
> The Option Length is the number of octets in the option counting the
> type, length, pointer, and overflow/flag octets (maximum length 40).
>
> The Pointer is the number of octets from the beginning of this option
> to the end of timestamps plus one (i.e., it points to the octet
> beginning the space for next timestamp). The smallest legal value is
> 5. The timestamp area is full when the pointer is greater than the length.
>
> The Overflow (oflw) [4 bits] is the number of IP modules that cannot
> register timestamps due to lack of space.
>
> ```
> The Flag (flg) [4 bits] values are
>
> 0 -- time stamps only, stored in consecutive 32-bit words,
>
> 1 -- each timestamp is preceded with internet address of the
>      registering entity,
>
> 3 -- the internet address fields are prespecified. An IP
>      module only registers its timestamp if it matches its own
>      address with the next specified internet address.
> ```
>
> The Timestamp is a right-justified, 32-bit timestamp in milliseconds
> since midnight UT. If the time is not available in milliseconds or
> cannot be provided with respect to midnight UT then any time may be
> inserted as a timestamp provided the high order bit of the timestamp
> field is set to one to indicate the use of a non-standard value.
>
> The originating host must compose this option with a large enough
> timestamp data area to hold all the timestamp information expected.
> The size of the option does not change due to adding timestamps. The
> intitial contents of the timestamp data area must be zero or internet
> address/zero pairs.
>
> If the timestamp data area is already full (the pointer exceeds the
> length) the datagram is forwarded without inserting the timestamp, but
> the overflow count is incremented by one.
>
> If there is some room but not enough room for a full timestamp to be
> inserted, or the overflow count itself overflows, the original
> datagram is considered to be in error and is discarded. In either case
> an ICMP parameter problem message may be sent to the source host [3].
>
> The timestamp option is not copied upon fragmentation. It is carried
> in the first fragment. Appears at most once in a datagram.
>
> Padding:  variable
>
> The internet header padding is used to ensure that the internet header
> ends on a 32 bit boundary. The padding is zero.